# "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified" when updating a LocalReport parameter and refreshing it -- only when done quickly --

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, reporting-services

I have a WinForm (MVP) application, in which I have to show a LocalReport in a ReportViewer and update it using some textbox/numericUpDown.

The LocalReport just needs parameters, every input is setting a parameter.

This is the code where I set the LocalReport in the form:

```
 public LocalReport ReportToShow
    {
        set
        {
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200308/vs2010-rdlc-c-how-can-i-set-a-localreport-object-to-a-reportviewer
            //assign report Path
            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = value.ReportPath;

            //get a list of actual parameters in the report, with the value set @ String.Empty
            var newParams = value.GetParameters().Select(t => new ReportParameter(t.Name, String.Empty)).ToList();

            reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(newParams);



            //show the report for the first time
            reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
```

And this is the code that ***sometimes*** (will explain below) causes the exception:

```
private void UpdateParam(String name, String value)
    {
        reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new[] {new ReportParameter(name, value)});
        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

This method is bound to the TextChanged/ValueChanged event of my inputs. Basically, every time a input changes the report is refreshed.

This is the exception:
[image: Exception]

Note that the report has just 2 parameters now, and both are set. No datasource needed.

Why ***sometimes***:

- The exception is thrown the first time I show the form, since I programmaticaly update the textbox/numericupdown, and the events are fired "quickly".
- The exception is thrown when i type 2 strokes in the same time or even when I type *really* quick.
- The exception is **not** thrown when I type normally in the inputs.

The idea I have is that the reportViewer.RefreshReport() is async internally and when a event is fired before the completation, it will cause an exception.

Other things you may be interested:

- Stack trace:
  [image: Stack trace, looks like async]
- **Even if the exception is thrown, the report is rendered correctly!**

Debugging is becoming hell, any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *some* time spent against this issue, I "solved" this updating just the data structures (a dictionary) when the user changes some input, and refreshing the report using a timer, only when something is changed.

It looks that 250ms is a reasonable interval for the timer.

Ugly... but it works and the issue was becoming frustrating.